# Тест из 100 вопросов, и выводит их все сразу, а надо по 1

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть 100 вопросов, все 100 в одной форм, и через POST отправляются в контроллер, можно ли через jquery сделать чтоб вопросы выходили по 1 ? то есть временно скрыть остальные вопросы

пример:

```html
<FORM action="" method="post">
<select name="question1" id="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
<select name="question2" id="">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Вы их выводите средствами PHP? И они у вас все сразу на странице?

Comment: все вопросыиз базы идут через php,да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```js
$('.select').change(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (next.length != 0) {
    next.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="select">
    <select class="select" name="question1">
      <option value="">1</option>
      <option value="">2</option>
      <option value="">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="select" style="display:none;">
    <select class="select" name="question2">
      <option value="">4</option>
      <option value="">5</option>
      <option value="">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="select" style="display:none;">
    <select class="select" name="question2">
      <option value="">7</option>
      <option value="">8</option>
      <option value="">9</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Можно скрывая текущий и показывая следующий:

```js
$('.select').change(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (next.length != 0) {
    $(this).hide();
    next.show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="select">
    <select class="select" name="question1">
      <option value="">1</option>
      <option value="">2</option>
      <option value="">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="select" style="display:none;">
    <select class="select" name="question2">
      <option value="">4</option>
      <option value="">5</option>
      <option value="">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="select" style="display:none;">
    <select class="select" name="question2">
      <option value="">7</option>
      <option value="">8</option>
      <option value="">9</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Добавить `else $(this).parent().submit();`  и он будет автоматом сабмитить при выборе последнего ответа

Comment: чувак, помоги плиз, а если у меня select внутри div-а, как на кнопку назначить открытие след diva

Comment: Я обновил ответ на `div`